# How do you read a part of key-value data without loading the whole datastore

Tags: matlab, key-value-store

Take for example from the `ds = datastore('mapreduce.out')` datastore from this [example](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-and-analyze-data-in-keyvaluedatastore-for-mat-file.html)

If you did a `readall(ds)` you would retrieve a list of all keys and values, which looks like:

```
  Key        Value 
________    _______

'AA'        [14930]
'AS'        [ 2910]
'CO'        [ 8138]
'DL'        [16578]
'EA'        [  920]
'HP'        [ 3660]
'ML (1)'    [   69]
'NW'        [10349]
  .            .
  .            .
  .            .
```

What if you only wanted data from the Keys 'AA', 'DL' and 'NW'? Do you still have to read all the data in the datastore at once?

How can you find a list of keys in the datasource and only read data corresponding to these keys?

Comment: Im guessing the list of keys is not immense (e.g. less than 1e3 elements), in that case you can just read all of them and then extract the ones you need. Alternatively you can try the textscan function, though Im not sure you can navigate this file line by line.

Comment: this doesn't work when the list of keys is immense and the dataset is in the gigabytes though.

Comment: use an okvs such as leveldb.